# Corrupted directory after sshfs hard killing

Tags: linux, mount, sshfs

I've mistakenly mount huge network directory using `sshfs` util. Trying to `umount` it leaded to hand-up this process, so I decided to `kill -9` appropriate `sshfs` process.

This leads to that folder `contracts` in which network directory was mounted became in this inconsistent state:

```
[root@xxx mnt]# ls -l
ls: cannot access contracts: Transport endpoint is not connected
total 260
d????????? ? ?    ?         ?            ? contracts
```

How I can fix it? (I can not delete neither chmod it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`umount -f -l /mnt/contracts` should fix it.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow, and then reply, Thank you